# S7 Edge second sim disappears randomly

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge, dual-sim

I've got a dual-sim Galaxy S7 Edge (SM-G935FD) this spring and everything was fine until a week ago my second SIM started to disappear randomly. Basically I wake up the phone after a while and I see no indications of the second SIM: no signal bars and "No SIM card in slot 2" message in settings. Rebooting the phone sometimes solves it for a while -- the second SIM becomes visible and works as expected but after a few hours it disappears again.

Things that I have tried so far:

- wiping out cache partition
- forcibly setting second sim to "2G only"
- manually choosing mobile operators for both sim cards
- swapping sim cards -- problematic sim card would still disappear after a while,
  now from slot 1.
- putting the problematic sim card into another phone -- it works just fine, not disappearing at all
- factory reset

The issue still persists. Currently my first sim (the one which works well) is set to "auto (4g/3g/2g)", also mobile data goes through that card. My second sim (the problematic one) is set to "2g only", although setting to "auto (3g/2g)" gives same result.

Inspecting phone logs with `adb logcat` while the second sim is invisible hasn't revealed anything suspicious..

My software:

Android 7.0

ROM: G935FXXU1DQEJ

Build: NRD90M.G935FXXU1DQGN

Comment: Try to put some other sim instead of problematic one and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared to be a bizarre SIM issue: after replacing the SIM I haven't seen such behavior for more than a month. It's weird that the SIM would fail sporadically and a reboot would fix it, also that it would happily work on other devices. Anyway, this is hopefully solved now.